# sfdx force:org:list hangs

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, vs-code

When I run the following command in either the VS Code terminal window, or a Windows Command Prompt, it returns all of the orgs, but hangs:

```
sfdx force:org:list
```

[image]

Is there some other way I should be calling this command to prevent the screen from locking?